# Is there a way to use both FFTW and cuFFTW in one C++ program?

Tags: c++, cuda, fft, fftw, cufft

I'm writing a piece of code that uses FFTW3 library and wish to port it to GPU using CUDA. The easiest way to do this is to use cuFFTW compatibility library, but, as the documentation states, it's meant to completely replace the CPU version of FFTW with its GPU equivalent. After adding `cufftw.h` header it replaces all the CPU functions and the code runs on GPU.

But is there a way to have **both** CPU and GPU versions of FFTW in my code so I can switch between them during runtime, e.g. via a checkbox in a user interface? Or is the only way to to this is to use native cuFFT API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even without looking at the library headers: Yes.

A simplistic solution would be having different compilation units each include just one of the libraries, and only exposing your own custom functions/classes/etc. to the rest of the application. This way the two libraries' headers will not interfere with each other.

However, it's quite possible that there's a better solution. I would look at `cufftw.h` to see what exactly nVIDIA is doing in there and how exactly it "replaces" CPU functions.

Comment: Thanks, having different compilation units seems to be a pretty good solution! I looked into both headers and they only declare functions, can't find anything special there. All the definitions are kept in the dynamic libraries so it seems that I can't even change the names of the functions declared in the headers. Probably I could build my own version of FFTW from the source code and change the names of the functions but it does not seem to be an elegant solution...

Comment: Just want to confirm that it really works:) Fast and easy, thank you for the answer!